# В чем причина задержки корутины в UnityWebRequest?

Tags: unity3d

Есть сервер и клиент, сейчас на одной машине, но проблема в том, что есть задержка действий в 3 секунды, которая, судя по всему, возникает в корутине ожидания, но почему возникает - непонятно, ибо я получаю просто текст с этой же машины. Подобная операция должна выполняться за доли секунды.
Сама корутина выглядит примерно так:

```
IEnumerator GetText() {
        UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest("http://www.my-server.com");
        www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        yield return www.Send();//эта строка 3 секунды ждет

        if(www.isError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            // Show results as text
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
```

Временная проверка следующая:

1. Command sendind 7/17/2017 9:54:19 PM
2. Prestarting Courotine 7/17/2017 9:54:19 PM //этот метод создает новый UnityWebRequest, когда мы получаем команду
3. Startind courutine 7/17/2017 9:54:19 PM
4. OnHttpRequest 7/17/2017 9:54:22 PM
5. Get responce 7/17/2017 9:54:22 PM
6. Remove connections 7/17/2017 9:54:22 PM
7. Command sendind 7/17/2017 9:54:22 PM
8. Prestarting Courotine 7/17/2017 9:54:22 PM
9. Startind courutine 7/17/2017 9:54:22 PM
10. OnHttpRequest 7/17/2017 9:54:25 PM
11. Get responce 7/17/2017 9:54:25 PM

Можно увидеть что задержка в 3 секунд. Как и почему мне не очевидно. В чем могут быть причины, основываясь на предоставленных мной данных?

Comment: В UnityWebRequest передаёте что-то на localhost или что? Если да, то, вероятно, сервак ваш локальный тупит.

Comment: При каждом вызове задержка по 3 сек?

Comment: Да, при каждом вызове задержка 3 секунды. Она статичная. Всегда ровно 3 секунды. Плюс я также загружал картинку из сети, но с помощью устаревшего www и там тоже примерно 3 секунды задержки было, хотя я списывал это на то, что может быть сервер далеко. Хотя эти события могут быть не связаны. 

Да, в UnityWebRequest передается localhost

Comment: Какая версия unity?(UnityWebRequest был экспериментальный до версии 5.4, и даже после было куча проблем с ним, например фризы https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/wsa-in-tablet-mode-application-starts-a-bit-shifted-deployed-in-portrait-mode?_ga=2.216772565.2107306142.1500426225-2081680126.1450758401). UnityWebRequest пробовали на другом сайте?